# Ubuntu 19.04 on X11 could not detect secondary display but on Wayland it can

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

Hardware:
Laptop with iGPU (Intel HD Graphics 630) and dGPU (nVidia GTX 1070) + external monitor

My external monitor used to work on both X11 and Wayland. But after playing around with `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` in my attempt to disable my iGPU  I reverted my changes and did an `update-initramfs -u`. I'm not sure if that caused it but that's what I remember doing before getting this problem and I already reverted my changes.

Afterwards, logging in on X11 my external monitor goes blank and going to my Display Settings it shows as if I'm only having a single monitor. What's puzzling is that when I login on Wayland mode, it's able to make my external monitor to work.

How do I figure what's wrong with my X11 and how do I fix this?

UPDATE:

I noticed on the logon screen I can see my external monitor showing default background which confirms it's working. But upon logging in on X11, the monitor goes blank and enters power saving mode. This does not happen when on Wayland.